# Open-source static code analysis tools for C++

Tags: c++, 64-bit, static-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What open source C++ static analysis tools are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available)

Which open-source static C++ (not just C) code analysis tools are most suitable for porting code to 64-bit platforms?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `visual studio`, there is a switch "detect 64 bit portability issues".

If you use `gcc` compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` then it should also inform you about portability issues.

You can also use `splint` (C only) and so on. There are lots of such tools.

There are also commercial ones for C++ (from wikipedia):

```
* Green Hills Software DoubleCheck — static analysis for C and C++ code.
* LDRA Testbed — A software analysis and testing tool suite for C & C++.
* PC-Lint — A software analysis tool for C & C++.
* QA-C (and QA-C++) — deep static analysis of C for quality assurance and guideline enforcement.
* Red Lizard's Goanna — Static analysis for C/C++ in Eclipse and Visual Studio.
* BEAM — IBM Checking Tool for Bugs Errors and Mistakes
```

Comment: +1 @suma  If anyone can find a C++ equivalent, I would like to know (and I have trawled for years, so do not expect to be surprised)

Comment: I know it is 12 years on, but most (commercial) C tools now support C++ too - and some of the Open-Source do too.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something like this because of [LARGEADDRESSAWARE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052028/detect-pointer-arithmetics-because-of-largeaddressaware/3054178#3054178).

As far as I know, there is no such open source tool available. There is [Cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page), but compared to commercial tools it offers only very few checks, and none of them seems to be 64b related.

To some extent you can use your compiler built-in functionality ("detect 64 bit portability issues" for Visual Studio, `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` for gcc). If you want deeper analysis, commerical [PC lint](http://www.gimpel.com/) or [PVS-Studio Code Analyzer](http://www.viva64.com/pvs-studio/) are probably the best known.

Other questions dealing with the same subject:

- [What open source C++ static analysis tools are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available)
- [C++ static code analysis tool on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97454/c-static-code-analysis-tool-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

We use [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page). I'm not sure how much it applies to 64-bit, but perhaps it's worth taking a look at.