# PE header and LARGEADDRESSAWARE not evaluated for DLL modules?

Tags: windows, dll, portable-executable, virtual-address-space

In the PE header there's a flag to indicate whether the binary is LargeAddressAware or not.
The PE header itself exists for both, *.exe and *.dll.

Is it really the case that Windows OS evaluates this flag for the parent executable, only?
Is it completely ignored for all DLL modules?

So why should i enable the LAA linker flag for DLLs if nobody is evaluating it?

I was having the following in mind:
Is there a way to force Windows issue a warning in case a LAA enabled exe loads a module that is not compiled as being LAA?

Also see related question: [Drawbacks of using /LARGEADDRESSAWARE for 32 bit Windows executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288728/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it really the case that Windows OS evaluates this flag for the parent executable, only?

Yes.

> Is it completely ignored for all DLL modules?

Yes.

> So why should i enable the LAA linker flag for DLLs if nobody is evaluating it?

You should not. It is pointless to do so.

> I was having the following in mind:
>   Is there a way to force Windows issue a warning in case a LAA enabled exe loads a module that is not compiled as being LAA?

No there is not.

---

The thing is the heap is process wide. It is shared by all modules. You cannot have some using a LAA heap and others not. So only the executable gets a chance to make this decision. The flag is in the PE file format which is common for DLL and EXE. But it only has meaning for EXEs.