# Java 32 bit memory threshold on 64 bit Windows 10

Tags: java, performance, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I've got some software that requires around 1500m of memory to run correctly. I force this amount at the start using xms and xmx to make sure it has the memory it needs. I used to run it on Windows XP or Windows 7 and it ran fine. After switching to Windows 10 I suddenly find I don't have enough memory to run it anymore. After researching how memory in Java works I came across the following information on this page:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit

> Due to various additional constraints such as available swap, kernel address space usage, memory fragmentation, and VM overhead, in practice the limit can be much lower. On most modern 32-bit Windows systems the maximum heap size will range from 1.4G to 1.6G.

It sounds like I've been running on the edge of what 32bit Java is capable of. Testing the limits of my machine it seems my current max is about 1.1g. At the moment switching to 64bit may not be on the table, so I'm trying to figure out how to get back the roughly .5g I've lost from my max memory threshold. I've tried researching all of the things listed in the FAQ that could affect it.

- available swap: This appears to be the page file or virtual memory. Apparently increasing this can sometimes help. Sometimes when I increase this I see a temporary improvement after a restart, but the fix never seems to last if I restart again.
- kernel address space usage: This seems like it’s the memory ceiling for the operating system. Nothing we can do the change this right?
- memory fragmentation: Supposedly Windows 10 is actually better at handling this than previous versions of Windows. So this shouldn’t be a factor.
- VM overhead: Seems like it’s referring to RAM usage from other virtual machines. Other than Java I don’t think I have anything else running that counts as a virtual machine.

Is there any solid way to identify and correct what could be causing the difference in performance between versions of Windows? It's super frustrating because I have more physical memory now than ever, but the only RAM that matters is the RAM JVM is allowed to use, which is now somehow less.

### Update

I hear you. I know I can fix it easily switching to 64 bit; my question is how I can fix it without doing that. Isn't it helpful to understand how JVM determines it's max heap for scholarly reasons as well as practical? I doubt there are many apps that hit the upper limit of 64 bit Java, but wouldn't Java behave the same way if there were?

Comment: Is there any valid reason to use a 32-bit version of Windows?  Are you really running on hardware so old it cannot support 64-bit Windows?

Comment: "VM overhead" is not referring to RAM usage from other virtual machines. It's referring to the memory needed by the VM you're running, for it's own internal needs.

Comment: *"What valid reason is there not to use it?"* Lack of memory space for a single process (e.g. VM). Seems like a pretty valid reason to me.

Comment: On 32-bit windows each process' address space is limited by the architecture to 4GB.  Given the necessary overhead, including the JVM itself, the maximum was always between 1 and 1.5 GB. (BTW, swap has nothing to do with this).  I would be really surprised if the space available under WinX was larger than under Win7.  You might shoehorn it in today, but you're one Windows Update away from hitting the ceiling again.  Time to retire the old notebook and move to something a bit more modern.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm running 64 bit windows it's java that is 32 bit.

Comment: @Andreas I'm not running 32 bit Linux. Where did you read that at?

Comment: _"I'm running 64 bit windows it's java that is 32 bit"_ -- OK, I'll bite... WHY?  Are you maxed out at 4GB physical memory?  Try running 64-bit Java and see what happens.

Comment: @JimGarrison I agree we should be using 64 bit, but those in a position to make that decision may not agree. I know 64 bit java works, but it breaks other software we rely on.   I'm trying to get back the functionality we had until we can figure out how to upgrade properly.

Comment: @JimGarrison I realize it&#39;s a silly situtation, but I&#39;m trying to view it as a technical challenge. 64 bit Java likely behaves the same way at it&#39;s upper limits so maybe some body with a more resource intensive app could still make use of an answer.

Comment: Wow, the tech gore on my last comment. All I did was hit edit and it replaced all my apostrophes. Ha.

Comment: *"I know 64 bit java works, but it breaks other software we rely on"* Then run that software on 32-bit Java. You can have both 32-bit Java and 64-bit Java installed at the same time. You can also have multiple Java versions (6, 7, 8, and 9) installed at the same time too, if needed.

Comment: @andreas I can't run both because the all the software in questions runs inside of sort of manager or container that points all it's pieces at the same JRE. However I found a way to get around the problem until I have an opportunity to properly switch to 64 bit. See my edit in the main post.

Comment: @JimGarrison I found a way to get around the problem until I have an opportunity to properly switch to 64 bit. See my edit in the main post.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to figure out why the memory was different between systems, but I did learn of a `LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag I could set on the Java.exe that would allow it to have up to 1G more memory.

Out of several tools people were typically using to set the flag I found this custom coded python script that attempts to set it on any .exe file you hand it. Using that I was able to feed it the Java.exe and now everything works.

It would appear that setting this flag is not typically recommended, but no side effects so far. I'll use this until I can properly switch everything to 64 bit.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1288

```
# See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#PE_Header
# and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

import struct

IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE = 0x0020
PE_HEADER_OFFSET = 60
CHARACTERISTICS_OFFSET = 18

def set_large_address_aware(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb+')
    # Check for MZ Header
    if f.read(2) != b'MZ':
        print('Not MZ')
        return False
    # Get PE header location
    f.seek(PE_HEADER_OFFSET)
    pe_header_loc, = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))
    # Get PE header, check it
    f.seek(pe_header_loc)
    if f.read(4) != b'PE\0\0':
        print('error in PE header')
        return False
    # Get Characteristics, check if IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE bit is set
    charac_offset = pe_header_loc + 4 + CHARACTERISTICS_OFFSET
    f.seek(charac_offset)
    bits, = struct.unpack('h', f.read(2))
    if (bits & IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE) == IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE:
        return True
    else:
        print('large_address_aware is NOT set - will try to set')
        f.seek(charac_offset)
        bytes = struct.pack('h', (bits | IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE))
        f.write(bytes)
    f.close()
    return False

if set_large_address_aware('file.exe'):
    print('large_address_aware is set')
else:
    print('large_address_aware was NOT set')
```

Comment: So this "fixed" the problem?

Comment: @rogerdpack appears to be a work around that is also used by others and addresses the OP's immediate difficulty.

Comment: @rogerdpack Kind of. Apparently, nobody understands the details of how Java's max heap is determined. Or at least there isn't an easy way to do so. The best solution I could find was to give Java more memory to work with and hope that it didn't squander it.

Comment: See also this older discussion (2010 timeframe) [Drawbacks of using /LARGEADDRESSAWARE for 32 bit Windows executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288728/drawbacks-of-using-largeaddressaware-for-32-bit-windows-executables) though this may or may not apply to Windows 10 or 64 bit Windows.