# 64bit architecture - character pointer truncated while returning from function

Tags: c++, c, windows, 64-bit

#### Environment:

Windows x64 bit with 5GB RAM.   My binary is a 64bit one built with compiler of version - "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for x64"

#### Environment setting:

Microsoft suggests to set the below registry key to test 64 bit applications and I have set the same in my box. The problem doesn't occur if i don't set the below registry because the program is placed at a low address.  The same registry key is mentioned in the discussion - [As a programmer, what do I need to worry about when moving to 64-bit windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544296/as-a-programmer-what-do-i-need-to-worry-about-when-moving-to-64-bit-windows)

To force allocations to allocate from higher addresses before lower addresses for testing purposes, specify MEM_TOP_DOWN when calling VirtualAlloc or set the following registry value to 0x100000:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\AllocationPreference

#### Sample code:

```
char *alloc_str()
{
    char *temp;
    temp = (char *) malloc(60);
    /* copy some data to temp */
    return temp;
}

main()
{
    char *str;
    str = (char *)alloc_str();
}
```

#### Analysis:

`malloc` returns address `0x000007fffe999b40` which is stored in `temp` but when the pointer is returned to `main()`, `str` gets only the second half - `0xfffffffffe999b40` and I am not able to access the data at that location.

Comment: I think you're going to need to say what you are actually doing. You mention PAE. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: What is the return type of your function? And to what variable is the return value assigned?

Comment: You might have a situation when your pointer is intermediately stored is some storage of a 32-bit type. Such a transition cuts the other 32 bits.

Comment: please paste the whole function. if it's too large, then reduce it into a sensible repro.

Comment: What do you mean by "truncated?" What is `sizeof(char*)` for your program?

Comment: Why do you use `str = (char *)alloc_str()` rather than `str = alloc_str()` in `main`? The code looks fine to me though. For what it's worth, top-down memory allocation does not place you *program* in high memory, it places the *dynamically allocated memory* in high memory.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. I run with top-down allocation all the time for the obvious reasons. I can only conclude that either the code you have published is not what you are running, or that somehow your configuration is messed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points about style, which could help to diagnose this kind of problems. As you use `malloc` I suppose that it is compiled as a C program. In that case, do not typecast when it is not necessary. Excessive typecasts may suppress the warnings telling you that you have not correctly declared your functions. If there is no prototype and the function definition is in another module then your call `str = (char *)alloc_str();` will suppress the warning that the function is used without declaration and the default declaration of C will be used, i.e. all parameter and return value will be considered as `int` .
Same thing with the `malloc`, if you forgot the right include, your typecast will suppress the warning and the compiler will assume the function returns an `int`. This might be already the cause of the truncation.
Another point, in C, an empty parameter list is declared with `(void)` not `()` which has another meaning (unspecified parameters).
These are 2 points that differ between C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

The registry setting you refer to selects top-down memory allocation. You state that this setting will "place program in high address space". It won't do that. What this does is force the Windows memory manager to allocate memory from the top of the address space.

What's more since you are running under 64 bit Windows, I fail to see where PAE comes into play. That would be something used on a 32 bit platform.

I would guess that you are compiling a 32 bit app and so inevitably your pointers are 32 bits wide. But that is only a guess due to the lack of information.

In short your question is impossible to answer because you haven't told us what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

David, thanks for your time and suggestion.  The sample program was not working because I had not included `stdlib.h` in my C file and so the pointer returned by malloc was 32 bit. The problem I faced was with a production code which was bit different from the sample code.

tristopia, Your explanation is absolutely correct. I was facing the same problem.

In my production C files, I was facing the problem as below

**a.c**

```
call_test1()
{
 char* temp;
 temp = (char *)test1();
}
```

**b.c**

```
include stdlib.h
char* test1()
{
 char *str;
 test = (char *)malloc(60);
 /* copy some data to test*/
 return str;
}
```

When `str` was returned by `test1()`, the pointer contained 64 bit address (I analyzed the rx registry (which stores the return value of a function)  in windbg using "r rx") but when it was assigned to `temp`, it got truncated to 32 bit address).

The problem was due to

1. Not including signature of `test1()` in the a.c file
2. Typecasting the return value to char *

Modified source

**a.c**

```
char * test1();
call_test1()
{
 char* temp;
 temp = test1();
}
```

**b.c**

```
include stdlib.h
char* test1()
{
 char *str;
 test = (char *)malloc(60);
 /* copy some data to test*/
 return str;
}
```

I got the solution by trial and error but tristopia explained the reason.

#### 64 bit notes

1. Use %p instead of %lx to print an address of a pointer in 64 bit environmnent.
2. Include function signature and try to avoid typecasting pointers
3. On Windows,
   If you recompile your C/C++ code into a 64-bit EXE or DLL, you must test it with the AllocationPreference registry value set.

To force allocations to allocate from higher addresses before lower addresses for testing purposes, specify `MEM_TOP_DOWN` when calling `VirtualAlloc` or set the following registry value to `0x100000`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\AllocationPreference
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have to ask if you are using the correct compiler settings and linking against the correct C runtime library.